# how to get a even gap in container bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the small mobile view why does bootstrap stick the container right next to the scrollbar. I would like an even gap just like on the left-hand side. Do I have to change bootstrap to do this?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/11mdaswx/embedded/result/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class = "panel-body">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <h2>06/14 -</h2>
                    </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
<!--            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class = "panel-body"> -->
                    <h2> Some header here <br><small>Progrm </small> </h2>

                    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                      <dt>Key modules:</dt>
                      <dd>list</dd>
                      <dd>list </dd>
                      <dd>list
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Bootstrap, but i see that this rule: `padding: 0px 0px 0px 50px;` is being applied to your `body`. either change it to `padding: 0px 50px` or `padding: 0px`. Again, I'm not experienced enough with Bootstrap to even know why that rule is there, maybe someone else can answer that?

Comment: @DavidAlsbright that's not bootstrap. It's in the OP's code.

Comment: @serakfalcon Ah I did scan the CSS box and must have missed that, I just assumed it was a bootstrap thing! thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `body` has a `padding: 0px 0px 0px 50px;` which will cause the left side to get a 50px padding, but not the right side.

The direction for the padding (and every other css selector) is:
`selector: up right down left`

So, to fix your problem, add a 50px padding in the right direction and end up with: `padding: 0px 50px 0px 50px`.

If it is in fact bootstrap that defines this you can override by defining this style in a `.css` that is included after bootstrap:

```
body {
  padding: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
}
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

change the formatting you have on `body` from

```
padding: 0px 0px 0px 50px;
```

to

```
padding: 0px 50px 0px;
```

You did this, Bootstrap has nothing to do with this.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/11mdaswx/2/)